# PostgreSQL: Select table columns of given type

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a table `table1`, I can get a list of all columns of, say, the `double precision` type with:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE data_type = 'double precision' 
  AND table_name = 'table1';
```

How can I select just these columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is similiar to `SELECT *` but `*` should also recognize type.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(ID SERIAL,col1 INT, col2 double precision,
                    col3 VARCHAR(100), col4 double precision);

INSERT INTO table1(col1,col2,col3,col4)
VALUES (1,2.0,'a',4.0), (10, 3.0, 'b', NULL);
```

In my opinion the right way is just to specify column names in `SELECT`:

```
SELECT col2, col4
FROM table1;
```

To make this easier you could write simple query that will generate column list for you:

```
;WITH cte(data_type, tab_name) AS
(
   SELECT 'double precision'::text, 'table1'::text
)
SELECT *
    ,FORMAT('SELECT %s FROM %s',
         COALESCE((SELECT string_agg(column_name, ',')
          FROM information_schema.columns
          WHERE data_type = c.data_type
            AND table_name = c.tab_name), '*')
          ,c.tab_name) AS result_query
FROM cte c;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5a0e0/41/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════════════╗
║    data_type      ║ tab_name  ║         result_query         ║
╠═══════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║ double precision  ║ table1    ║ SELECT col2,col4 FROM table1 ║
╚═══════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════════════╝
```

Of course you can play with dynamic sql or even wrap it with function, but I would not go this path.

Comment: I think the moral of the story is that you probably shouldn't do this in SQL if you want to automate the process. Instead, use your favorite programming language to select the table names and use it to programmatically construct a second select.

Comment: Of course we can generate 'SELECT' scripts, but how to execute it inside the query?